# Has Tales From the Floating Vagabond Been Re-released?

Tags: tales-from-the-floating-vagabond

Or better yet, has Tales From the Floating Vagabond been updated any time since it debuted in the early 1990s?

(For those unfamiliar, it was a fairly small entirely humor-driven game. Imagine The 3 Stooges, every action/adventures/fantasy/sci-fi movie ever made and more than a hint of inspiration from Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.)

Comment: There is also an official website at thefloatingvagabond.com for news, announcements, etc.

Comment: @Lee Converted that to a comment from an answer, as it's not an answer (you don't have enough rep to comment so that's reasonable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it on PDF, [right here](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=2010&it=1). There's also a fan site [here](http://tffv.vagabond-network.com/index.shtml).